# Vega scanner with angular app - "Local Filesystem Paths Found"

Tags: angularjs, macos, webpack

Scanning  Angular 5.2.0 application with Vega scanner is showing the below Risk:

```
   Local Filesystem Paths Found
```

But you can see from the screenshots it is coming from angular-webpack. How to add the configuration to webpack and tell don’t use the absolute path of our filesystem.
I am not added any absolute path anywhere in my application.

So why the webpack is taking absolute path and exposing it in public files?

[image]

[image]